# How to create the table without @Id field in spring using jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using spring boot and jpa to create the table but I need to create table without **@Id** primary key column.It is not giving me to make the table without this @Id field. How to get this using spring data jpa?

LetterDoc.java

```
package com.ashwin.springsecurityangular.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "letter_doc")
public class LetterDoc implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "letterNo")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Letter letter;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "documentId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Document document;

    private String docFile;

//i omitted getters and setters and both constructor
}
```

It ask me the @Id field need.So there is error like:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ashwin.springsecurityangular.model.LetterDoc
```

In this table i am avoided to make @Id field but it is not giving me.How to achieve this?

Comment: The JPA ID needn't correspond to the database PK - it just has to be a unique column or combination of columns. If you have 2 columns forming a unique ID then you can use a composite JPA ID. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Composite_Primary_Keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA Specification clearly narrates that an Entity class must have a unique, immutable ID. However there are some hacks you can give them a try.

1) Maintain UUID for this purpose.

```
@Id
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
private UUID uuid;
```

2) Create a DTO/POJO representation of data fields in view layer, then execute a SQL Native query, then map the result set to your class

Comment: it is creating the uuid column or u can suggest me that both of them become primary key

Comment: yes there will be a column named uuid in table, and this column will be used.

Comment: i dont need this uuid column .. without adding extra column can't i make those two fields primary key?

Comment: you can make use of constraints here like, @Table(uniqueConstraints=
       @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"letterNo", "documentId"}) however this cannot replace primary key. So to answer your question you will still require a PK here

Comment: If these columns are unique then isn't he is looking for is a composite id with no need for the UUID?

Comment: while saving.. "UUID": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

**USE JPA PROJECTIONS**
In your case you dont have a primary key so use JpaProjections to get the fields you want
first declare Entity as

> ```
> @Entity
> @Immutable
> ```

set your Repository

```
public interface AddressView {
    String getZipCode();
}
```

Then use it in a repository interface:

```
public interface AddressRepository extends Repository<Address, Long> {
      @Query("SELECT ADDRESS from TABLE WHERE address =  ?1")
    AddressView getAddressByState(String state);
}
```

note ADDRESS entity in above is a placeholder
just make it

```
Public class ADDRESS{
@Id
Long id;
```